# Issues in Collection Item comparision in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to iterate a collection, it contains the ID of an HTML element. If I tried to compare the ID (i.e., Collection Item) with a hard coded string, it gives a RUN TIME ERROR. - Robot Framework and Selenium

> Evaluating expression ''[u'Convert To String', u'DEFAULT']' !=
>   'DEFAULT' AND' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

My Code is

```
*** Variables ***
@{HeaderCollection}=    DEFAULT    ONE    TWO    THREE


*** Test Cases ***
Click Items
    :FOR  ${item}  IN  @{HeaderCollection}
    \      ${header}    Set Variable    Convert To String    ${item}
    \      Run Keyword If    '${header}' != 'DEFAULT'    click element      ${header}
```

I tried the following code too

```
*** Test Cases ***
Click Items
    :FOR  ${header}  IN  @{HeaderCollection}
    \      Run Keyword If    '${header}' != 'DEFAULT'    click element      ${header}
```

Kindly assist me how to compare a item which is present in collection with a hard coded string value.

Comment: The code you provided does not generate the error you say it does -- there is no `AND` in the error message or in the test case. Have you considered logging `${header}` right before the `run keyword if` statement? I'm guessing it doesn't have the value you are assuming it does.

Comment: Your last block of code worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${header}    Set Variable    Convert To String    ${item}
```

In the line above, you are attempting to run the keyword `Set Variable` by passing it another keyword `Convert to String` which is the incorrect usage.

Seeing as all the items `@{HeaderCollection}` are Strings to begin with, there is really no reason for this line to exist at all, but if it is absolutely required, it should be as follows:

```
${header}    Set Variable    ${item}
```